# facebook javascript sdk fb_xd_fragment?

Tags: javascript, facebook, sdk

I am using the facebook javascript sdk to embed a like button in my page.

What is fb_xd_fragment? I see it appends to the end of my url like http://www.example.com/controller/?fb_xd_fragment, and this is causing some nasty recursive reload of the page.

Comment: I am getting the same behavior, the server gets hit with two requests - 1 with the standard URI; the other with URI?fb_xd_fragment. However this seems to be only happening in IE - more specifically IE7. Did you manage to get more info on this? All there is from FB: http://forum.developers.facebook.com/viewtopic.php?pid=232516 and a bug opened: http://bugs.developers.facebook.com/show_bug.cgi?id=9777

Comment: Yes, very specific to IE7, I used the Iframe version instead, hopefully someone will fix that bug.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

After many weeks of trying to find a solution it looks like what is needed is a custom channel url as mentioned here:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.init

All I did was create the **channel.html** file containing this single line:

```
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
```

Then I added the channelUrl : line so the final result looks like this:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div> <script>  
 window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
     FB.init({
       appId  : 'MY APP ID',
       status : true, // check login status
       cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
       xfbml  : true,  // parse XFBML
      channelUrl  : 'http://www.example.com/channel.html' // custom channel
     });   }; 

   (function() {
     var e = document.createElement('script');
     e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
     e.async = true;
     document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
 }());</script>
```

Make sure to add a comma after xfbml : true if it was your last line. I'm not familiar with Javascript so I don't know if I'm taking full advantage of this but I know it prevents the fb_xd_fragment issue and allows FB comments in IE. As far as I can tell, this is the ONLY solution available online. Any further tweaks are welcome.

Comment: I did this and also added xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml" into my <html> tag, and it's working now! Very annoying issue. I added the code you're posting there, and then below on the page just printed a like box and a comment box.

Comment: What's the final URL you put into channelURL ? We tried that here, with a custom html page on our server and it tries to create a "facebook page", really weird.

Comment: I had to add the xmlns:fb="facebook.com/2008/fbml"; as Ferran did or it would constantly poll. That was the final bit that has fixed it :)

Answer (score 3):

Solved with the iframe like button.

Answer (score 1):

The fix for this bug can be found here:

http://wiki.github.com/facebook/connect-js/custom-channel-url

Answer (score 1):

a1anm's link is good for cleaning up the mess that this causes, but there's a way to prevent it from happening.

Set 'channelUrl' to a locally hosted channel page. See http://threebrothers.org/brendan/blog/facebook-connect-ie-fb_xd_fragment-iframe/ for details.

Comment: hi can i directly put channelUrl: http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js
y nid another html???

Answer (score 1):

The bug and the fix are now documented at http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/fb.init/

Answer (score 1):

I used the approach within script to define the channelUrl to a page on my site, but I still got multiple hits back to that page.

After watching the resulting traffic with WireShark, I noticed they (Facebook) use a channelUrl for some of their own internal calls, also passing fb_xd_fragment - I instead used that URL for the channelUrl, redirecting it away from my site.

I have multiple Like buttons on my site using fbml instead of frames, and on IE7, I no longer get a hit back from Facebook with the fb_xd_fragment parameter.

Not sure if this is best practice but it seems to work.

I set this value for the channelUrl:

'http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect/xd_proxy.php'

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Although the answer above from github seems like an answer to another question, it does work well. 
UPDATE: link is broken - try http://blog.colnect.com/2010/10/fbxdfragment-bug-workaround.html

Answer (score 0):

affer few days research and expriment with all solution on internet at last i come up with combine of this

Change your head of your page:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:og="http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/"  xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml" lang="en-US">
```

here the cocde put this where you want likeit button is:

```
<div class="yourclass" style="z-index: 10;">
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js" ></script>
<script>FB.init({appId: '1234yourappidhere', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true});</script>
<fb:like href="http..yourencodedurlswillputhere" layout="button_count" width="150" action="recommend" colorscheme="light"></fb:like></div>
<script> document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].style.display='block';</script>
```

credit wellcome : http://www.xaluan.com

Answer (score 0):

The Channel hack did not work for me.
So I just added above all other content in my PHP file some code that 301 redirects to the URL without the fb_xd_fragment addition:

```
$url = "http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

if (isset($_GET['fb_xd_fragment'])) {
$url = str_replace("?fb_xd_fragment=","",$url);
header( "HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently" ); 
header("Location: {$url}");
exit();
}
```