# Integrating Facebook to the leads to blank pages on some browsers / fb_xd_fragment

Tags: facebook

On my site http://colnect.com I've implemented the "Facebook login" button and on some pages the "Facebook like" button using FB's new JavaScript API. It all appears to be working seamlessly on ff/opera/chrome etc.

It seems like a problem with Facebook's JavaScript API which happens on some browsers (I've gotten reports for older IEs and browsers of mobile).

Seems the JavaScript code is appending fb_xd_fragment parameter to the request URL and thus creates leads the user to a blank page. I've found a similar question (yet different which is why I opened this one) on: [facebook javascript sdk fb_xd_fragment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2955012/facebook-javascript-sdk-fb-xd-fragment)

The solutions presented there weren't helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED: the fix at http://wiki.github.com/facebook/connect-js/custom-channel-url helped out
At first I didn't try since it seemed unrelated. It does work though.

Comment: link broken now... what was it?

Comment: I've written the solution here: http://blog.colnect.com/2010/10/fbxdfragment-bug-workaround.html