# Has Facebook fixed fb_xd_fragment bug?

Tags: javascript, facebook

Couple month ago I was running into fb_xd_fragment bug with facebook's like button.

So I was using this [work around](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2955012/facebook-javascript-sdk-fb-xd-fragment) by setting up channelUrl.  It's been a while but do I still need to do this work around or did facebook finally fixed this issue? Can I just paste the HTML5 code from facebook [plugin page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/)?

Comment: The channelUrl method is the only supported way of dealing with this as far as I know - it's in the JS SDK docs