# Django like button not showing

Tags: django, facebook-like

after following the instructions [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-like-button) I have set up django-facebook-like app but the problem is that I cannot see any like button on my page. is there a particular tag I must use in order to display the button or does the button automatically display at the bottom of every page after setting up. I am confused about the last part though. I dont really understand [this addition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2955012/facebook-javascript-sdk-fb-xd-fragment). Can anyone help me. What am I missing

base.html

```
</head>
{% load like_button %}
<body>

{% like_button_js_tag %}
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: any 404s in the console ?

Comment: @karthikr no there is not. I have a custom 404 page though